# IdentityDbContext, DbContext and Relationships‏

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I need some help in order to create relationship between application user and my business entities using my own DbContext. I have two DbContext, one is for Identity and another for my Business Entities.

```
public class IdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
 {
        public DbSet<Singles> Single { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Country> Country { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ethnicity> Ethnicity { get; set; }
 }
```

The above works good for me. If I move the above DbSet properties into my own DbContext, it start throws some foreign keys error related to IdentityUserLogin table etc..And this is because I am trying to create a relationship between my Application User with Single and Single also have relationship with Country and Ethnicity. Is it possible to move the above DbSet properties into my DbContext and create relationship between them like now using with IdentityDbContext?

Answer (score 0):

A better idea would be to use the *IdentityDbContext* only, instead of using your other context. That said, try to move everything into the identity context. This will work, because the identity context inherits the normal context.

Comment: OK. Could you please let me know how can I disable lazyloading in IdentityDbContext. I found out even If I place my Configuration to disable Proxycreation and Lazyloading to false, it still loads the navigation properties where as it only expects to load when I use "Include" in my query.

Comment: Do you have some code examlpes. I find it strange that setting lazy loading to false still loads your releted entities. Btw: removing virtual from the navigational property definition will remove the possibility to lazy load that relationship (even with lazy loading enabled). Also check if ef's Local (in memory) data is related to your non-lazy loading effect (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592872.aspx)

Comment: @Horizon_Net - Out of curiosity, is this _strictly_ required? Or is there a way for an `DbContext` implementation to reference entities using `IdentityDbContext`? I'm a bit reluctant to move all of my entities over to a new base class just so some of them can reference the `ApplicationUser` class.